# Json placeHolder API - Fetch Data white condition

Tags: reactjs, api, axios, next.js, jsonplaceholder

I've been trying to integrate my posts into my user table for 2 days with the Json PlaceHolder API with nextJS. I can't seem to find the right logic and after many tries and searches I could use a little help.

I tried the filter() method but this one doesn't seem very conventional to me. I'm convinced that there is a very simple way with conditions but I can't integrate it into my map()

```
export default function Home() {
  //State
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  //Get Users
  useEffect(() => {
    const url = `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com`;
    axios
      .get(`${url}/users`)
      .then((response) => setUsers(response.data));
    axios
      .get(`${url}/posts`)
      .then((response) => setPosts(response.data));
  }, []);

  const listPost = posts.filter((post) => {
    const listUser = users.filter((user) => {
      if (post.userId === user.id) console.log('matching post');
      else {
        console.log('undefined post');
      }
    });
  });
  return (
    <div>
      <main className='container'>
        <table className='rwd-table'>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>id</th>
              <th>name</th>
              <th>username</th>
              <th>post-userId</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {users.map((user) => (
              <tr key={user.id}>
                <td>{user.id}</td>
                <td>{user.name}</td>
                <td>{user.username}</td>
                <td></td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </main>

      <footer>
      </footer>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You can modify the users array to add then `user.posts = []`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems like you want to `associate` users with posts, few things.

- You might don't need to set both users and posts on the state (thats 2 setStates) but you can just merge them together so yo end up with a data structure like `{ id: number, name: string, ..., posts: Array<Post> } // this is a user`, which is what you are looking for.

**BONUS:**

- Since Posts and users API calls don't depend on each other you can make those 2 calls at the same time, see

```
const [users, posts] = await Promise.all([
  fetchAxiosData("users"),
  fetchAxiosData("posts")
]);
```

- made `fetchAxiosData` so you don't worry about the HTTP layer at the component level
- Add `error` and `isFetching` state, its always good to have an idea if there is an error or you are loading (NOTE: some libraries like [swr](https://swr.vercel.app/es-ES) or [react-query](https://react-query.tanstack.com/) already handled this for you, you might wanna take a look)

I will leave the UI implementation to you, not sure how do you want to show the posts on the table, maybe just the title?

you can do `<td>{user.posts.map(({ title }) => title).join(", ")}</td>`

Here is the [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/staging-night-rm9ois?file=/src/App.js:1580-1586) for you to play around

Comment: thank you so much Ethaan. It's so much clearer now. I was trying to find a solution after my fetch but the problem came from the fetch. I did not think about it. I'll take a look at the documentation links. Thank you